# very short and basic question, is $(1,1]$ empty or is it $\{1\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Title says it all really. I was asked what is the union and intersection of all the sets $A_n=(1/n,1]$ where $n$ is natural. Right off the bat, $A_1=(1,1]$. is this an empty set? or is it $\{1\}$. I am unsure.

On one end, it says "does not include 1" but on the other end it does so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the general case to understand what is going on here:

$$(a,b] = \{x\in\Bbb R: a< x\le b\}.$$

In this case, $(1,1] = \{x\in\Bbb R: 1 < x\le 1\}.$ That is to say that if $x\in (1,1]$, it is simultaneously greater than $1$ and less than or equal to $1$. What does this tell you?

Comment: There is no such $x$

Comment: Precisely. That said, you *may* want to look at the problem statement a little more carefully. I would think that $n$ starts at $2$ (at least this is how I would phrase the question).

Comment: clearly says $\forall n \in \mathbb N$

Comment: Welp. I guess that makes the intersection part pretty easy!

Answer (score 2):

It is empty. By definition, $$(1,1] = \{x \in \Bbb{R}: x>1 \space \text{and} \space x \leq 1 \} $$